# document.getElementById Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, php, html

Having a progress bar linked to a progress bar.

#### Javascript code

```js
var i = 0;

var counterBack = setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    if(i<100){
      document.getElementById(<?php echo 'id=progress' . $row[0] ?>).style.width = i+1+"%";
      document.getElementById(<?php echo 'id=progress' . $row[0] ?>).innerHTML = i+1+"%";
    } else {
      clearTimeout(counterBack);
    }
}, 1000);
```

#### Issue

The console shows error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
```

#### HTML

My HTML is very simple

```html
<div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" <?php echo 'id=progress' . $row[0] ?> role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Using PHP.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Based on the error, you were trying to access the element which isn't exist in the UI . before accessing it should exist in UI.

Comment: document.getElementById just needs the ID - nothing else...ie, remove `id=`

Comment: `document.getElementById(id=progress1).style.width = i + 1 + "%";` will never work.  You need to remove the id= and quote the ID string progress1. Also `i + 1 + "%"` will be `11%` for i = 1
You have many such errors. Next time please post a [mcve] of the RENDERED HTML in a `[<>]` snippet.

Comment: please don't use PHP in `JAVASCRIPT` and and please don't use `var`, please use `const` or `let`; you can use let for i and const for counterBack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var i = 0;

var counterBack = setInterval(function(){
i++;
if(i<100){
document.getElementById('<?php echo "progress" . $row[0] ?>').style.width = i+1+"%";
document.getElementById('<?php echo "progress" . $row[0] ?>').innerHTML = i+1+"%";
} else {
clearTimeout(counterBack);
}
}, 1000);
you can't use id= inside getElementById 
and before and after php tags you must use '
sorry about my english but i share working code it's tested